# How to save PyQt -TableWdiget-Tabular Data in Python main file or SQL DB?

Tags: python, user-interface, qtablewidget

I am a civil engineering student developing a python gui based tool for engineering calculation.Since all the calculations are based on table as we does in the excel file, I wanted to know how to save a table data entered through GUI tableWidget? And how to perform the operations on multiple tables?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please take a minute to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly. Especially, what code do you have already, where is your specific problem, what does your input look like and what do you want your output to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download  [xlsxwriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter/1.0.2) which is a python package for writing to ms excel. in this example, am using a push button which will be used to export the data from the table to ms excel. You should rename self.tableWidget to the name of your table in case you changed the default name.

```
self.exportButton.clicked.connect(self.exporter)

def exporter(self, filename=None):
    if not filename:
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File'," "'.xlsx','(*.xlsx)')
    if filename:
        wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
        self.sheetBook = wb.add_worksheet()
        self.export()
        wb.close()

def export(self):
    row = 0
    col = 0
    for i in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
        for x in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            try:
                text = str(self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
                self.sheetBook.write(row, col, text)
                row += 1
            except AttributeError:
                row += 1
        row = 0
        col += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is helpful to me.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem using the mark on the left side of the answer provided